# CSS- HELP Checkbox issue on widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I've used a javaScript function to "build" a widget, call it on an HTML page and make it responsive using CSS.

Now, I've to use that same widget on an mvc.net application and i can't make it work like i want it. In the image shown bellow  "aluger","venda", "compra" and "permuta" all show up in the same line, and I want them to show up on different lines. I've used display:block and nothing happend. 
Those options are loaded automatic.
Can some one please help me?

CSS of DIV:

```
#div_maior {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

#div_global {
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding: .5%;
    border-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
   // overflow: auto;  
}
```

HTML OF THE WIDGET:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css"/>
    </head>
    <body id="body" onload="getFacetasAJAX()">
        <label id="div_maior">  
            <label id="div_global" style="display: inline-block">
            </label>

            <label id="div_resultados" style="display: inline-block">

            </label>
        </label>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the CSS for `#div_resultados` as well? Thanks

Comment: not fully sure I understand you. try removing `style="display: inline-block"` from `<label id="div_global" style="display: inline-block">`.
If I understand you correctly this is what might causing the elements to show in the same line